# Access ListItem.Properties from Javascript COM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, properties

Is there a possibility to access the `ListItem.Properties` from the Javascript COM? All I'm seeing is the possibility to read all `Fields`. There also is the funny `[SP.ListItem.LoadExpandoFields()][1]`, but I don't know what it does.

Comment: I believe you can access this by soap so you would be looking at accessing the soap api via JQuery, failing that make your own handler and call that.

Comment: With soap you mean the SP webservices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
item.get_fieldValues().MetaInfo
```

Full example (with ES5):

```
var listTitle = 'TestList', itemId = 1;

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var item = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle).getItemById(itemId);
ctx.load(item);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  var properties = item.get_fieldValues().MetaInfo.trim();
  properties = properties.split(/\n/).filter(function(p) {
    return !!p;
  }).map(function(p) {
    p = p.split(/\|/);
    var t = p[0].split(/:/);
    return {
      name: t[0],
      type: t[1],
      value: p[1]
    };
  });
  console.log(properties);
});
```

Comment: Nice! SharePoint 2013 will make our lives easier, but this is neat. Didn't know MetaInfo contained all properties.

Comment: Me neither actually. What I did was to inspect the payload sent from server to see if my properties were actually sent at all. Then I noticed that they were contained in `MetaInfo`.